# How to do POST instead of GET with the SPARQL package from R

Tags: sparql

> results <- SPARQL(endpoint,query,curl_args=list(style="post"))

**
Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body
Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 3 and html
Premature end of data in tag html line 1
**Error**: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body
2: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 3 and html
3: Premature end of data in tag html line 1
In addition: Warning message:
In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
  Unrecognized CURL options: style

I used curl_args=list(style="post"), but it was  Unrecognized CURL options: style

Comment: ehm, wouldn't it make sense to show query and also the endpoint URL in addition the single line of your R code? I mean, that's almost no information. by the way, the error messages looks more like the endpoint URL is wrong given that an HTML document is tried to be parsed which is mostly unlikely the result of a SPARQL query

Comment: the CURL args look exactly like the example in the manual, thus, this should be correct. are you using the correct package resp. version?

Comment: Thank for your respond. I ran with some queries and this was success with endpoint <- "http://dbpedia.org/sparql" ; But with long queries it was fail.

Comment: My query in Rq =paste("SELECT ?property ?value WHERE 
           {?mv ?property", " ?value.",
           "FILTER( ?property !=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>|| lang(?value)='en')",
           "FILTER( ?property !=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment>|| lang(?value)='en')",
           "FILTER( ?property !=<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>|| lang(?value)='en')",
           "FILTER( ?mv IN (",movie,"))",
           "}"
           ,sep="")

Comment: According to the source code, `POST` is only supported for SPARQL 1.1 Update queries but not for `SELECT`

Comment: Thank you so much. Perhaps I have to find another ways .